# Implement Gauss-Jordan elimination in Haskell

Tags: math, haskell, linear-algebra

We want to program the gauss-elimination to calculate a basis (linear algebra) as exercise for ourselves. It is not homework.

I thought first of `[[Int]]` as structure for our matrix. I thought then that we can sort the lists lexicographically. But then we must calculate with the matrix. And there is the problem. Can someone give us some hints.

Comment: This is a bit vague: "But then we must calculate with the matrix. And there is the problem." What calculations are you having a problem with?

Comment: I must add a line a to line b: add (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x + y) : add xs ys. But how can I make it that the first element of the 2 line will be 0.

Comment: `[[Int]]` is generally bad idea for matrix, because I doubt whether you want O(n) complexity access. Consider `Data.Array` (low level) or even `hmatrix` (as Jan suggests) hackages.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using matrices from the [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) package. Among its modules you can find both a fast [implementation of a matrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Data-Packed-Matrix.html) and a lot of [linear algebra algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Algorithms.html). Browsing their sources might help you with your doubts.

Here's a simple example of adding one row to another by splitting the matrix into rows.

```
import Numeric.Container
import Data.Packed.Matrix

addRow :: Container Vector t => Int -> Int -> Matrix t -> Matrix t
addRow from to m = let rows = toRows m in
  fromRows $ take to rows ++
             [(rows !! from) `add` (rows !! to)] ++
             drop (to + 1) rows
```

Another example, this time by using matrix multiplication.

```
addRow :: (Product e, Container Vector e) =>
          Int -> Int -> Matrix e -> Matrix e
addRow from to m = m `add` (e <> m)
  where
    nrows = rows m
    e = buildMatrix nrows nrows
        (\(r,c) -> if (r,c) /= (to,from) then 0 else 1)
```

Cf. [Container](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Numeric-Container.html#t%3aContainer), [Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Data-Packed-Vector.html#t%3aVector), [Product](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Numeric-Container.html#t%3aProduct).

Comment: Could you add types? I believe they would help understanding the examples considerably

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier if you use `[[Rational]]` instead of `[[Int]]` since you get nice division.

You probably want to start by implementing the elementary row operations.

```
swap :: Int -> Int -> [[Rational]] -> [[Rational]
swap r1 r2 m = --a matrix with r1 and r2 swapped

scale :: Int -> Rational -> [[Rational]] -> [[Rational]]
scale r c m = --a matrix with row r multiplied by c

addrow :: Int -> Int -> Rational -> [[Rational]] -> [[Rational]]
addrow r1 r2 c m = --a matrix with (c * r1) added to r2
```

In order to actually do guassian elimination, you need a way to decide what multiple of one row to add to another to get a zero. So given two rows..

```
5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3
```

We want to add c times row 1 to row 2 so that the 7 becomes a zero. So `7 + c * 5 = 0` and `c = -7/5`. So in order to solve for c all we need are the first elements of each row. Here's a function that finds c:

```
whatc :: Rational -> Rational -> Rational
whatc _ 0 = 0
whatc a b = - a / b
```

Also, as others have said, using lists to represent your matrix will give you worse performance. But if you're just trying to understand the algorithm, lists should be fine.

Comment: Actually, you only need euclidean division to perform Gaussian elimination (it is more complex though).